# Hide/ show 'Add new record' in telerik:RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik-grid

So i have page contain telerik:RadGrid on top of the grid there Add new button i want when the user not allow to add new record to put visible =false 
else visible =true i want to do it in code behind

[image]

All I can find on net is how to disable the button, and this not what I want I want -  to hide/show it depend on user

Comment: Please provide some more info, code sample etc where you are exactly facing problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your grid's name as gridExample. `gridExample.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings.ShowAddNewRecordButton = false` will help you in hiding or showing based on the user.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before too.  I never found a RadGrid property where you can make the `Add new record` button invisible. The way I solved it was a little hackish. You can do this with CSS, or JQuery.

The name of the button is usually something like `ctl00$ContentPlaceholder1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$AddNewRecordButton`. So I've used javascript/JQuery to hide it. The javascript would look like:

```
$('#ctl00$ContentPlaceholder1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$AddNewRecordButton').hide();
```

You would need server-side (ASP) logic to put this code in your (client-side) JQuery page startup code.

For your page, you might need to change the name (above), if your grid is not named `RadGrid1`.  To find the name of your control, you can view source, or use the DOM debugger (F12 in InternetExplorer) and find the text "Add new record".

Answer (score 0):

You use call `ShowAddNewRecordButton`. Please ensure you call `MasterTableView.Rebind` depending on your logic.

```
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.CommandItemSettings
   .ShowAddNewRecordButton = true;
RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />` inside the MasterTableView like below

```
<MasterTableView>
     <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />
         <Columns>

         </Columns>
</MasterTableView>
```